# How do I avoid storing redirections in a boost::filesystem::path?

Tags: string, boost, path, boost-filesystem

I'm using [Boost::Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html) to traverse around directories in Linux.

Every time I need to re-define the path to be one directory back, I do something similar to this:

```
auto p = boost::filesystem::current_path();
p /= "../";
```

The problem is, that when I output 'p', it will show me the path with "../" still tacked on.
How do I get this evaluated each time I decide to go back a directory.  I would like going back a directory to make the path shorter- instead of making the path longer and longer every time.

I thought one of these functions might do it, as they take a path by reference,
`boost::filesystem::absolute(...)`
`boost::filesystem::canonical(...)`
but after calling them and re-outputting 'p', the result still shows a "../";

`path& make_preferred()` does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canonical` or `absolute` is the way to do it. Do you use the returned path? The given path is taken as a constant reference so it is not modified in place. From the boost manuals:

```
path canonical(const path& p, const path& base = current_path());
path canonical(const path& p, system::error_code& ec);
path canonical(const path& p, const path& base, system::error_code& ec);
```

> Overview: Converts p, which must exist, to an absolute path that has
>   no symbolic link, dot, or dot-dot elements.

Comment: This is correct. I made the mistake of thinking the path passed in would be changed. p = canonical(p); works.